# Forming an array from items in list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops

I am trying to create an array from data in a list of lists.

```
ac_name = 'ac'
dat = [['ab=55', 'ac=25', 'db =57', 'dc =44'],
       ['ab=75','ac =12', 'cg =11', 'pt =95'],
       ['ab=17', 'ac=62'],
       ['ab=97', 'aa=501', 'dc=12', 'dd=19']]
```

So I want to get a list that looks like this

```
ac = ['ac=25','ac=12','ac=62','']
```

and from this get

```
ac_values = [25,12,62,'']
```

All in all I want to convert dat into one large array.

I know this doesnt work because it is going through every item, so the output is however many elements there are in dat.

```
ac = []
for d in dat:
    for c in d:
        if ac_name in c:
            ac.append(c)
        else:
            ac.append('')
```

Comment: Your `else` block is inside the nested loop which means that for all the items in each list if the condition is not executed you'll have an empty string.

Comment: What if there are multiple `'ac='` in a sublist?

Comment: @Kasramvd thanks very much. I have not seen that before

Comment: And what do you mean with "array"? A numpy.array? An array.array? Usually a python array can only have one data type, not combined string and integer...

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in comment, your `else` block is inside the nested loop which means that for all the items in each list if the condition is not executed you'll have an empty string. You can use a flag to see whether the `if` block is executed in nested loop and append an empty string to the final result.

```
In [6]: ac = []
   ...: for d in dat:
   ...:     flag = True
   ...:     for c in d:
   ...:         if ac_name in c:
   ...:             ac.append(c)
   ...:             flag = False
   ...:     if flag:
   ...:         ac.append('')
   ...:         

In [7]: ac
Out[7]: ['ac=25', 'ac =12', 'ac=62', '']
```

But since this is not a much Pythonic way for dealing with problem, instead you can use generator expressions and `next()` function as following to create a dictionary out of expected result. In this case you can easily access keys or values as well.

```
In [19]: result = dict((ind, next((i for i in d if i.startswith(ac_name)), '=').split('=')[1]) for ind, d in enumerate(dat))

In [20]: result
Out[20]: {0: '25', 1: '12', 2: '62', 3: ''}

In [21]: result.keys() # shows number of sub-lists in your original list
Out[21]: dict_keys([0, 1, 2, 3])

In [22]: result.values()
Out[22]: dict_values(['25', '12', '62', ''])
```

Comment: how would i then incorporate looping through the column names. so if col = ['ab','ac','db','dc','cg','pt','dd'] ? where would that fit into the loop?

Comment: @SnookerRogers I don't see how this relates to your question and/or your expected output?

Answer (score 1):

```
ac_name = 'ac'
datas = [['ab=55', 'ac=25', 'db =57', 'dc =44'],
    ['ab=75','ac =12', 'cg =11', 'pt =95'],
    ['ab=17', 'ac=62'],
    ['ab=97', 'aa=501', 'dc=12', 'dd=19'],
    ['ab=55', 'ac=25', 'db =57', 'dc =44'],
    ['ab=75','ac =12', 'cg =11', 'pt =95'],
    ['ab=17', 'ac=62'],
    ['ab=97', 'aa=501', 'dc=12', 'dd=19']]

lst = []

for i,data in enumerate(datas):
    for d in data:
        if ac_name in d:
            lst.append(d.split('=')[-1])
    if i == len(lst):
        lst.append('')

print(lst)
```

**Output**

```
['25', '12', '62', '', '25', '12', '62', '']
```

Comment: This doesn't produce an empty string for the last list.

Comment: hey @zimdero nice to see your answer again. Nice solution.

Comment: I think this will not work if there are more items in `datas` after the one which has no `ac`.

Comment: @zimdero thanks. how would i then incorporate looping through the column names. so if col = ['ab','ac','db','dc','cg','pt','dd']  ?

Comment: you want to say that instead of `ac_name = 'ac'` you want to search `col = ['ab', 'ac']` ?

Comment: @zimdero yea exactly. so specify the unique 'cols' which are in 'datas', then loop through for each one.  my initial thoughts were to have a for loop for columns under the 'for d in data:' line in your code. 'for k in range(len(cols))' or something similar

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.chain` to flatten your list of lists. Then use a list comprehension to filter and split elements as required.

```
from itertools import chain

res = [int(i.split('=')[-1]) for i in chain.from_iterable(dat) \
       if i.startswith('ac')]

print(res)

[25, 12, 62]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this as folks have shown. Here is one way using list comprehension and higher order functions:

```
In [14]: ["" if not kv else kv[0].split('=')[-1].strip() for kv in  [filter(lambda x: x.startswith(ac_name), xs) for xs in datas]]
Out[14]: ['25', '12', '62', '']
```

If an exact key "ac" is desired, can use regular expressions too:

```
import re
p = re.compile(ac_name + '\s*')
["" if not kv else kv[0].split('=')[-1].strip() for kv in  [filter(lambda x: p.match(x), xs) for xs in datas]]
```

Answer (score 0):

After some puzzling, I found a possible solution

Process each element in each sublist individually: if it contains 'ac', then strip the 'ac=' part. If not, just return an empty string ''.
Then concatenate all elements in each sublist using string.join(). This will return a list of strings with either the number string, e.g. '25', or an empty string.
Finally, conditionally convert each string to integer if possible. Else just return the (empty) string.

```
ac = [int(cell_string) if cell_string.isdigit() else cell_string for cell_string in
      [''.join([cell.split('=')[1] if ac_name in cell else '' for cell in row]) for row in data]]
```

Output:

```
[25, 12, 62, '']
```

edit:
If you want to extend it to multiple column names, e.g.:

```
col_name = ['ac', 'dc']
```

Then just extend this:

```
cols = [[int(cell_string) if cell_string.isdigit() else cell_string for cell_string in
         [''.join([cell.split('=')[1] if name in cell else '' for cell in row]) for row in data]] for name in col_name]
```

Output:

```
[[25, 12, 62, ''], [44, '', '', 12]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ac_name = 'ac'
ac = []
ac_values = []

for value in dat:
    found = False
    for item in value:
        if ac_name in item:
            ac.append(item)
            ac_values.append(item.split('=')[-1])
            found = True
    if not found:
        ac.append(' ')
        ac_values.append(' ')

print(ac)
print(ac_values)
```

Output:

```
['ac= 25', 'ac = 12', 'ac=62', ' ']
[' 25', ' 12', '62', ' ']
```

Answer (score -1):

This will work for any length of `ac_name`:

```
ac_name = 'ac'
ac = []
ac_values=[]
for i in dat:
    found=False
    for j in i:
        if j[:2]==ac_name:
            ac.append(j)
            ac_values.append(int(j[len(ac_name)+2:]))
            found=True
    if not found:
        ac.append("")
        ac_values.append("")
print(ac)
print(ac_values)
```